# Find Head revision svn no working copy

Tags: svn, revision

I have a repo I am trying to get the HEAD revision number through code. There is no svn controlled working copy as everything is exported.

Tried: `svn info /var/svn/xyz`

But it says this is not a working copy.
All I need is the rev number.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

svn info accepts a remote repository as the path to check. Why not use that? [svn info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html)

You'll get the repository info back in an easily parsable format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    svnlook youngest /var/svn/xyz
```

It works fine for me:)